# Query xml table that contains name spaces such that it will be able to handle multiple values for an element

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser, xml-namespaces

```
       Column Name: xml_col, table name: my_table

     ROW 1: 

 <a:employees xmlns:a="abc.com/123" xmlns:b="xyz.net/456">
 <a:emp>
    <a:name>Scott</a:name>
    <b:favorites>
    <b:color>red</b:color>
    <b:color>orange</b:color>
   </b:favorites>
  </a:emp>
  <a:emp>
  <a:name>John</a:name>
  <b:favorites>
  <b:color>blue</b:color>
  <b:color>green</b:color>
 </b:favorites>
 </a:emp>
 </a:employees>
```

ROW 2:

```
 <a:employees xmlns:a="abc.com/123" xmlns:b="xyz.net/456" xmlns:c="pqr.edu/789>
 <a:emp>
<a:name>Tiger</a:name>
<b:favorites>
  <c:phone>apple</c:phone>
  <c:phone>samsung</c:phone>
 <b:color>purple</b:color>
 <b:color>pink</b:color>
  </b:favorites>
  </a:emp>
  <a:emp>
<a:name>peter</a:name>
<b:favorites>
   <c:phone>nokia</c:phone>
 <b:color>violet</b:color>
 <b:color>indigo</b:color>
  </b:favorites>
  </a:emp>
 </a:employees>
```

I am looking for a query which converts the above data into relational data, ex: 
The desired output should be like the sample image. Could someone please write a query for   the below requirement. Regular structures are not followed in the xml column which on which i am working.

```
  ![Sample][1]
```